# return var of img.onload = function()

Tags: javascript, return, onload

How is it possible to return the value of "summe"? Thank you!

```
img.onload = function() {
    orgWidth = this.width;
        orgHeight = this.height;

    factor = orgHeight / 480            // 1400 / 480 = 2.916
    calcWidth = orgWidth / factor       // 1000 / 2.916 = 342.935

    k++;

    summe += calcWidth;
    document.images[k].width = calcWidth;
}
alert(summe);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return summe;
```

But more importantly, return to what? This looks like a callback, meaning that you are defining a function that runs when the image loads therefore it will be invoked by the browser itself automatically and you won't be able to do anything with the returned value.

The only meaning that callback return values really ever have is that `return false` will usually halt event bubbling and prevent the default action ([and should not be overused](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)).

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: http://foto.hendrik-schicke.de/index.php/people

I need the summe to set the width of conveyor.css("width", parseInt(summe));

Comment: @Kibou so why not do that from inside the callback method? You do not know when the image will finish loading so the best you can do is set it when it is done. By the way when you use parseInt you almost always want to provide the second radix parameter of `10` otherwise it attempts to guess the radix and you will sometimes get very strange behavior. Try it for yourself `parseInt("010")` will guess base 4 and return 8

Comment: Also, don't use alert for debugging - use console.log() it is a lot more helpful and will prevent you from leaving debugging dialogs in your code that your users will see.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use a return-value you must at least have a function name to use it later like this:

```
var func_name = function() {
    orgWidth = this.width;
        orgHeight = this.height;

    factor = orgHeight / 480            // 1400 / 480 = 2.916
    calcWidth = orgWidth / factor       // 1000 / 2.916 = 342.935

    k++;

    summe += calcWidth;
    document.images[k].width = calcWidth;
}

var funcObject;

img.onload = function() {
    funcObject = func_name();
}
```

after this you can use funcObject anywhere to use your return value

Comment: Didn't help me. I am totally new to java.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the returned value?

Comment: Javascript @Kibou not Java. They have similar names and some similar syntax but they are VERY different programming languages, if you program javascript like Java you will have a lot of difficulty, it is far closer to languages like Scheme and IO